# Is there a jquery List plugin that will auto-sort items and has robust add/remove methods?

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui

I have been googling for hours looking for something to handle my situation. I am not skilled enough to write my own jquery plugin ..YET!!

The plugin should auto-sort the list, not as important as being able to add/remove items from the list easily. Themeroller capable would be a plus.

I would basically use anything as long as I could add a item to the list (or any other container for that matter), item is coming from a modal popup that is using ajax to search for the item. Once the item is found I want to click that item and have it added to the list and it would put it into the correct order based on alphabetic sort. I think where I am losing sight is the complexity of the item and needing to have the item contain:

1. The name of the item
2. a hidden value, [the int id of the item],
3. one or two checkboxes for turning on/off a feature for that item.

I am really open to any ideas, suggestions on a better process, or a pointer to a plugin that might get me close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [jQuery.TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) to sort all sorts of things. It should work with whatever you have in your item.
I don't see why you absolutely need the plugin to handle adding to the `<ul>` and auto-sort. Just write a simple function that `$("#myList").append(myNewItem)` and then call a re-sort of the list with `$("#myList").tsort()` (refined to what you need to sort).